# Bootstrap and fixed header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap with a fixed top navbar.

It is working fine on desktops. But my menu on mobile overlaps content which I don't want. I want nice sliding regular dropodown menu. How can I tell mobile devices to ignore that assigned class `navbar-fixed-top`? I want that effect to just be applied on Desktop browsers.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logos/vision-logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>      
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use "container-fluid" class instead of "container" and use media query which is available in current Bootstrap.

```
@media(max-width:767px){...}
@media(min-width:768px){...}
@media(min-width:992px){...}
@media(min-width:1200px){...}
```

It will keep your html completely responsive.